# summarise text using autosummarizer cross domain

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, summarization

IS there a open source text summarization api like [THIS Site](http://autosummarizer.com/index.php) 
For the time being i was using circumvent cross domain form posting limitation 
and was stuck how to access this above said sites feature from my page without an *API*

**NOTE:-** *Found Temporary solution by posting to form action referencing its address and page*

Comment: please give reason before down voting

Answer (score 2):

The site that summarizes text offers an API.

I would start by getting a developer key. Then you can use their summarizer through a dedicated channel.

Comment: it doesnt provide an api and developer key at current stage :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found another approach which gets the things done its cross domain form posting 
and i have got what i was looking for

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sachindivakar/2xmvnkr7/6/)

```
<form action="http://www.tools4noobs.com/" name="f1" method="post">
```

The Solution what i figured out was to learn how the system works in parent site(The Site in which you want to use the feature  ) if its simple form submission on click of button just use inspect element feature in the browser and copy the form and its contents then replicate the data in our page and in case of action for example in parent site,  we have to add `action="www.example.com/index.php"` so that form submission goes to parent site